# Dependency (Newtonsoft.JSON) not being loaded when exercised through my COM interface. Dependcy containg different version sub dependency?

Tags: c#, .net, com, dependency-management

I have a native client talking to a managed class library via a COM interface.

I am using a project (AutoRest - OS project from MSFT), which appears to take a dependency on NetwtonSoft.JSON. I am calling into this AutoRest project (I'm taking a dependency on AutoRest.Core) with a class library wrapper I've written. This class library wrapper defines a COM interface, which is called from a native application. I built a test client for my client library in C# (.NET), which works fine. However, when I use my COM interface, when it calls some methods from AutoRest.Core I get the exception:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=7.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I take this to mean it's trying to find Newtonsoft.JSON.dll (or a dependency of this). My gut tells me it can't find a particular version of Newtonsoft.JSON and/or is getting confused with other versions. I'm guessing this is because **my client library has a dependency on Newtonsoft.JSON** AND AutoRest (which in turn has a dependency on Newtonsoft.JSON, but a different version). This sound like where this issue is originating from? I've found that I can use Newtonsoft.JSON directly from my class library, but (presumably) any calls to Newtonsoft.JSON from within AutoRest (which my client library wraps), uses a different version of Newtonsoft.JSON, and hence causes this error.

So. how do I correctly deal with this?

I'm not sure what useful information I can give here. Please tell my what is useful in diagnosing this issue. If it helps, under my solution packages folder I have "Newtonsoft.Json.8.0.3". Error messages says it wants version 7. My **class library Newtonsoft.JSON dependency is v4.0.30319**. I'm not sure what version AutoRest uses, nor

In case it helps: for class library COM project I have "register for COM interop" checked in the project settings. I then generate the IDL from the register COM object, then convert the IDL to a header file which I include in my native project. I create an inproc server COM in the native client (CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER).

Comment: From what I remember not finding assembly and not finding specific version of the assembly are two different errors and you have clear distinction between those. In the second part of your question you say that you actually get error for mismatching error so in this case, I don't remember the exact syntax but the solution is to remove the assembly in separate folder and in the config file define the assembly adding the path to it in the XML. Sorry for not being able to write the exact code, but I belive you can see how this is done using google.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Just to clarify are you saying that this is a versioning situation or file not found situation?

Comment: `have "Newtonsoft.Json.8.0.3". Error messages says it wants version 7.` To solve this you have to provide direct path to the assembly. When you solve this problem we can proceed with the other (if it still persist). However one suggestion is that, if possible, just migrate one of the projects so that it matches the `Newtonsoft` version of the other. IMO a lot cleaner solution.

Comment: Thanks, I went to AutoRest.core source code, and ran "update-package Newtonsoft.Json -reinstall" in the package manager, which seems to of moved it to version 8. I then removed and re-added the reference to AutoRest.core from my class library, but not I'm getting an even worse error from LoaderExceptions: "Could not load file or assembly 'AutoRest.Core, Version=0.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)". Any hints ?

Comment: First restore the `AutoRest`. Then if possible, downgrade the version that you use in your own project to 7.0 (the same as the `AutoRest` version of `NewtonSoft`) or try to find how you could specify specific version of assembly in the config file (I know this is possible because that's the way I solved this kind of problems in the past) and just provide explicit definition for the assembly version of `NewtonSoft` you use from your project.

Comment: Hey, yup, that's what I did and I've now downgraded my managed project to version 7 and it's working :) Thanks :) However, I want to understand what's going on better... why can't I use the latest version! By the way AutoRest was failing to upgrade to 8 when I used NuGet see: http://pastebin.com/RUpch4Gi. Finally there is another dependency AutoRest.Swagger.dll, but when I use my native application, it throws an error saying it can't find it - I have to add this dll to the working directory (c:\users\pete\documents), despite I've specified it as a reference. Why is this? Thanks for your help:)

Comment: to be honest I don't have deep knowledge about this topic. It just so happens that I've faced similar problem in the past so I was able to give you some hints. In order to learn more I think you need to search for other sources or write another question here, in SO for this. But as you see such kind of questions don't get a lot of attention so I'm not sure if it's worth it. Maybe just try to find something worthy on the internet.