# Solving multiple versioned dependencies in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, com, dependencies, dependency-management

I'm trying to understand how I should correctly manage dependencies of different versions in .NET projects.

As per my post:

[Dependency (Newtonsoft.JSON) not being loaded when exercised through my COM interface. Dependcy containg different version sub dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36256694/dependency-newtonsoft-json-not-being-loaded-when-exercised-through-my-com-inte)

Where I was getting

> Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=7.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I had a (COM) project which had 2 dependencies - Newtonsoft.JSON **v8** and AutoRest.
Unfortunately, the AutoRest project had its own dependencies, one being Newtonsoft.JSON **v7**. This caused the error above when AutoRest loaded the Newtonsoft.JSON dll

I noticed the error only occurred when I was actually using my COM interface from a legacy application. When I ran my test client - aconsole application part of the same solution as the project within Visual Studio, the correct versions of DLLs were loaded. Only when I actually called the COM interface from my legacy application did I get the error above.

Fortunately I was able to change Newtonsoft.JSON version from 8 to 7 in my project, so that all versions of Newtonsoft.JSON were 7. However, in the future I might not be so fortunate. Hence, I'm asking what is the proper way to resolve this? Why did it happen?

Thanks

Comment: You need a binding redirect from config.  Loading that through COM is trickier.

Comment: so you're saying I need to mess with a config file within my solution? That's how it's normally done. Then I have another layer of complexity when I add COM loading into the mix?

Comment: It's just an XML tag and won't mess with any nuget or etc other config, very simple and elegant solution if you ask me

Comment: The only "proper" way is to have the dependencies installed in the GAC.  That however is risky with a very common DLL like Newtonsoft.Json, that company *really* needs to get its versioning strategy sorted out.  It is not clear what you now do to help the CLR find these dependencies and what you can demand from the client app (not usually a config file) so the second-best solution is not obvious.  Use the GAC.